# ASP.NET garbage collection: is referencing static class property dangerous?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, garbage-collection

Let say 'MyModel' class containing following property:

public List ListOfAlbumsTitles => AlbumsHelper.ListOfAlbumsTitles;

`AlbumsHelper` is a static class. Does it mean, that the object of MyModel wouldn't be collected automatically because of referencing static class property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, instances of `MyModel` will be disposed of fine. What `MyModel` stores is a reference to something that happens to be in-use elsewhere (namely in `AlbumsHelper`).

References are one-way where garbage collection is concerned. So a reference from `Foo` to `Bar` will keep the `Foo` alive so long as the `Bar` lives. The other way around means nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it the other way around.

Any object can be collected as soon as there's no reference *to that object*. Outgoing references have no bearing on object lifetime.

Imagine what would happen if that wasn't the case - the garbage collector could never collect anything that didn't `null`-out all of the references it has to other objects. That's not very useful.

Comment: yeah, that's was pretty obvious. thx for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, the logic goes the other way, if AlbumsHelper was not a static class this assignment would prevent it from being collected. But because the class is static it does not matter.